# Ubuntu laptop when clsing lid no more wifi

Tags: wireless

When I close the lid on my laptop and then open it again and sign in the wifi does not work anymore.
I have already tried to restart the network manager with `sudo service network-manager restart` but that didn't help!
Anyone knows what the problem might be

Comment: Can you re-enable it by pressing the appropriate function key or hardware switch?

Comment: No not at all! I can press the function key but it does not do anything... And in the upper right corner when I click on the connections icon then the entry `Enable wifi` is grey and not even possible to be changed

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have to check

system->preferences->power management, and this is the place where you can set, how the laptop has to behave when the lid is closed.

Comment: There it says 'suspend' on both battery and charger but I don't want to change that behaviour!